# BigQuery parse date not working on %Y%W format

Tags: sql, date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Everything is in the screenshot:
I have a column with date string in format `%Y%W`. I want to get the date of the Sunday of the corresponding week (eg. `202201` returning `2022-01-09`)

The `PARSE_DATE` function cannot parse the data correctly, it just return the year correctly but doesn't parse the week number

As from [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date):

> The format string fully supports most format elements except for %a,
> %A, %g, %G, %j, %u, %U, %V, %w, and %W

So how to solve the problem?

Data sample:

```
week_year
202204
202208
202203
202205
202202
202207
202206
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077649/how-can-i-parse-a-date-as-week-year-in-google-bigquery) is related but doesn't provide answer to the problem

[image]

Comment: Given that a year-week is not a date and doesn’t contain enough information to determine a date, it can’t be converted to a date, obviously. Which date, of the 7 days in a week, are you expecting it to convert to?

Comment: [Give this a try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198916/3122921) maybe.

Comment: @MarcinJ overcomplicated solution, but it works indeed

Comment: @NickW i would like to get the date of the Sunday as the result; example 202201 as 2022-01-09

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extraxt date from ISO Week (201905) BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196270/extraxt-date-from-iso-week-201905-bigquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly but working solution (inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198916/3122921)):

```
DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
          CONCAT(SUBSTR(week_year, 1, 4), '0601')), isoyear ), INTERVAL CAST(SUBSTR(week_year, -2) AS int64) WEEK), INTERVAL 1 day),
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working :

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%g %V %u', '19 46 1')
```

It will give you the monday (1) of the week 46 of the year 2019